# Detect whether a specific property of an entity has been altered when 'putting' the entity?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Looking for an efficient way to check whether a specific property of a `db.Model` has been changed vs. the version stored in the datastore before `putting` it. Obviously I would like to avoid getting a fresh instance from the database! Is it possible? Something like this:

```
class MyClass(db.Model):
    prop = db.StringProperty()

instance = MyClass()
instance.string_property = 'string'
instance.put()

instance2 = db.get(instance.key())
instance2.string_property = 'string2'

instance2.put() #would like to detect that string_property was altered!
```

Answer (score 2):

I think thats a bad idea.

If you have a look at the code for db (you should really be using ndb now) there is a lot going on under the hood for each property/model (metaclasses are used here heavily) and depending on the class/property and or value being assigned you could start getting some real odd behavior and or bugs.

It doesn't mean you should, but consider what you are doing carefully ;-)

I would consider either using hooks (se nick johnsons blog for some ideas blog.notdot.net/2010/04/… ) or switch to ndb and use it's pre/post hooks (see model hooks  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#hooks )

Comment: how exactly would I use hooks to accomplish this?

Comment: One way would be using be defining a post_get hook (another excercise for the reader. or use the ndb which already has post get hooks)  When you retrieve the entity, store the property values or a checksum in non persistent instance variable.  Then when you go to put use the pre_put hook to check what values have changed or if anything has changed and perform what ever notification you require before the put.

Comment: THis is also better than setattr overriding as the value could in theory change a couple of times before the final put , and end up back at the original value hence no notification would be required ;-) or multiple notifications are sent.  e.g. using a integerproperty and you keep adding some value in a loop.

Comment: OK, from what I understand: after you `get` an instance, make a copy of the variable you want to detect (in `post_get`) and then in `pre_put` it should be trivial to compare the variable you're about to `put` with the original value. Is that about right?

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is just a basic Python programming question:

```
class MyClass():
    prop = 'init string'

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        print name + ' is being updated to ' + value

    test = MyClass()
    test.prop = 'summing else'

    prop is being updated to summing else
```

Comment: I think thats a bad idea.  If you have a look at the code for db (you should really  be using ndb now)  there is a lot going on under the hood for each property/model (metaclasses are used here heavily) and depending on the class/property and or value being assigned you could start getting some real odd behavior and or bugs.  You should consider either using hooks (se nick johnsons blog for some ideas http://blog.notdot.net/2010/04/Pre--and-post--put-hooks-for-Datastore-models ) or switch to ndb and use it's pre/post hooks.

Comment: I'm using hooks on this model - how would I use them to detect update of a specific property?

Comment: @Tim Hoffman - if you make an answer using db hooks as per Nick's blog that could be the accepted solution I think :-)